# Subset column values into separate vectors using 'for' loop in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, for-loop, vector

I have this `data.frame` and vector:

```
 df <- data.frame (fruit = c(rep("apple", 5), rep("banana", 3), rep("cherry", 6), rep("date", 4)),
                   letter = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "d", "f", "b", "c", "f", "p", "q", "r", "d", "p", 
                        "x", "y")
                   )
 my_vector <- c("apple", "banana", "date")
```

Now I would like to use a `for` loop, which results in vectors with as names the elements in `my_vector` and as elements those listed in the `letter` column.

So expected outcome is like this:

```
 apple <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
 banana <- c("a", "d", "f")
 date <- c("d", "p", "x", "y")
```

Thanks you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can `subset` to keep only `fruit` in `my_vector` in the data and `split` it into list of vectors.

```
list2env(with(subset(df, fruit %in% my_vector),split(letter, fruit)), .GlobalEnv)

apple
#[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"

banana
#[1] "a" "d" "f"

date
#[1] "d" "p" "x" "y"
```

`list2env` does write the list of vectors as separate vectors in global environment but usually it is good practice to keep data in the list and not separate them in individual vectors.

---

A `for` loop solution would be with `assign` -

```
for(vec in my_vector) {
  assign(vec, df$letter[df$fruit == vec])
}
```

Comment: The `rlang` package also has a [`env_bind()`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/env_bind.html) function than can make use of quasiquotation.  I think `assign` here is pretty clean, although the `rlang` approach does have the nice [`caller_env()`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/caller_env.html) which allows for assignment at any level of scope.

Comment: This a terrific! Thank you!